# Install Laravel for one domain only

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, host

I have a host which supports multiple FTP accounts for addon domains. There's a new project I'm working on which I intend on using Laravel. All the tutorials I found said that I need to reroute my host from public_html to Laravel's public folder.
The thing is I want Laravel to be only included in this new project's folder, not on all of my other domains that I have online already. 
How can I install composer and create a new project inside of my new project's folder only?
I have contacted my host support and they gave me SSH access, which is working already.

Comment: How do you have your current domains set up? Do you have access to the nginx/apache configuration?

Comment: They're setup by FTP accounts that redirect them to the domains' main folders. I do have access to the `etc` folder, but I can't seem to find the configuration file. But I'm pretty sure I have access to it, as I reached support once and they said I could change it.

Comment: So a domain/ftp account has a directory, and inside of that directory is public_html where the web files go?

Comment: You may want to look into how to install Laravel on a shared server, since the instructions may be similar.

Comment: Which domains' folder is inside of the public_html

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you are using apache2 and you have access to the configs

go to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and edit the config for the domain you want to be the laravel project

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName you-newprojects-domain.com 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/newproject/public
  <Directory /var/www/public_html/newproject/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache2 with `sudo service apache2 restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

for nginx digital ocean has a simple tutorial for how to configure virtual hosts in step 5
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

You just have to point the domains root to public_html/newproject/public

then when you go to that domain laravel will be loaded

then if you have composer and have a composer.json in the folder you can do `cd /var/www/public_html/newproject/` then `composer install`

or `cd /var/www/public_html/` to create the project

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel newproject
```

Comment: If I change the first step you said by creating an FTP account that redirects my domain to this FTP account's folder will it work as well? Or I do need to do it manualy?